# codeigniter how can i display data in view from this model

Tags: codeigniter

This is request_report function in my **report_model** how can code tabular data in my view passed by controller

```
function request_report($from, $to, $member_filter )
    {
        $this->db->select('requests.request_id,items.item_type,items.quantity,items.item_unit,items.item_name, requests.item_id, requests.quantity_requested, requests.quantity_delivered, requests.purpose');
        $this->db->from('requests', 'items');
        $this->db->join('items', 'items.item_id = requests.item_id');
        $this->db->where('created_time >=', $from);
        $this->db->where('created_time <=', $to);
        if ($member_filter != 'null') $this->db->where('created_by', $member_filter);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0 ) {

        echo '<table id="requests" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                  <th>Items</th>
                  <th>Quantity Requested</th>
                  <th>Quantity Available</th>
                  <th>Quantity Delivered</th>
                  <th>Purpose</th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>';

            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {

                echo '<tr>';

                echo '<td>';
                echo $row->request_id;
                echo '</td>';
                echo '<td>';
                echo $this->get_item_type_name($row->item_type);
                echo '</td>';
                echo '<td>';
                echo $row->item_name;
                echo '</td>';
                echo '<td>';
                echo $row->quantity . " " . $this->get_unit_measurement($row->item_unit);

                echo '</td>';
                echo '<td>';
                echo $row->quantity_requested . " " . $this->get_unit_measurement($row->item_unit);
                echo '</td>';
                echo '<td>';
                echo $row->quantity_delivered . " " . $this->get_unit_measurement($row->item_unit);
                echo '</td>';
                echo '<td>';
                echo $row->purpose;
                echo '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';

            }

        echo '</tbody>
          </table>';


    }
    else{

        return '<h4 style="text-align: center; padding: 37px;"> No Matching Requests Found </h4>';
    }
}
```

**and this is my view**

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
<?php echo $this->report_model->request_report($from, $to, $member_filter)>
</div>
```

my question is how can pass data from model to view through controller, not just calling model directly in view, and i need the tabular data in model to be in view, am looking for any help thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my question is how can pass data from model to view through
>   controller, not just calling model directly in view, and i need the
>   tabular data in model to be in view, am looking for any help thanks!!

In  your controller say method is `index()`

```
<?php
class Site extends CI_Controller{

function index()
{
   // this you can also put in  __construct 
   // if you want to share same model across other methods

   $this->load->model('report_model'); 

   // And call your model function like below
   $data = $this->report_model->request_report('2015-12-10', '2016-03-10', 'some_user');

   // load view
   $this->load->view('bootstrap_view',array('model_output' => $data));
}

}
```

and in your view, say `bootstrap_view.php`

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
<?php echo $model_output;>
</div>
```

Also note you can make use of **table class** in codeigniter, where you can set template of your interest, for more details follow below link

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/table.html

Comment: great Thanks Akshay Hegde, helped me a lot

Comment: @turaco Glad to know it worked out, [you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)